# Accessing RaspberryPi from network with GUI (VNC on ArchLinux)

Tags: vnc, arch-linux, raspberry-pi

I've just installed ArchLinux on RaspberryPi. I would like to be able to connect to RaspberryPi with GUI, but there is no X server installed.

What packages should I install to be able to use VNC for GUI login if I won't be connecting RaspberryPi to any TV using HDMI, just SSH and VNC?

Answer (score 1):

The Arch Wiki is chuck full of information that will apply to the Raspberry Pi also.
See:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginner%27s_Guide
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vnc